# VS Code textmate rules scope grouping

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions, textmate

In a VS Code theme, are the following two scopes equivalent?

```json
"scope": "entity.name.type, entity.name.class, entity.name.namespace, entity.name.scope-resolution"
```

```json
"scope": [
    "entity.name.type",
    "entity.name.class",
    "entity.name.namespace",
    "entity.name.scope-resolution"
]
```

I wasn't able to find any docs explaining the second form.

**First form**

Copied from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4e8408d4c4dafae88f771691920bb54d7ab57c81/extensions/theme-monokai/themes/monokai-color-theme.json#L206)

**Second form**

An [example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4e8408d4c4dafae88f771691920bb54d7ab57c81/extensions/theme-monokai/themes/monokai-color-theme.json#L135) of the second form

**Update**

Reading some parts of [vscode-textmate](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate/blob/8961b1554acbb649bdce0d236ab0fd78180447af/src/theme.ts#L91) code, I think they are equivalent.

Comment: Where did you see the first form? It's not valid JSON, so I wonder where this is actually being used.

Comment: @MikeLischke I just copied part of it. Many themes use that form. I really don't get what is wrong with that (apart from missing braces that I didn't copy). And also I made a mistake creating the second form, edited now. I have updated my question with link to both forms.

Comment: Oh, I missed that this is a normal string, sorry. I guess this is all about what the parser of these files allows. They can accept a comma separated list in a string or an array (which would make parsing a tiny bit simpler). So yes, I agree, they are equivalent in their meaning. Why do you ask in the first place?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure they are equivalent, because I was not able to find any documentation regarding second form.